Importing Database Process Route with Alternatives
I have built a model to simulation an industrial process flow.
My model is essentialy composed by two agents:
the agents product, and the agent process.
Both the agents are population and their value is imported from an excel database.
Here the structure of the model:
enter image description here
Here the agent Main, the agent product enter in the model by the source block and they are sent to the agent Process by the exit block.
The agent Product has two collection: c_processstep that is a Linked List (string) that contains all the process step in the right order, and another collection called c_Timing that contains all the process time in the same order.
I will share you the structure of the database to make you understand:
the database is composed by two excel sheets:
enter image description here
enter image description here
the problem is that some of my processes are alternative, i will make you an example:
enter image description here
The logic that i want to implement is the follow:
Anylogic must recover both the alternatives from the DB and it
and should decide for himself on which machine to carry out the process, the choice should be of this type:

If both machines are free, prefer the faster one
If the faster machine is saturated then go to the slower one

Any advice?
Thanks in advance
Please note that the real model has a huge numbers of process and a huge number of machines.
I sincerely have no idea of how to solve this problem. I'm a beginner

Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Else, try to break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help

also, only use the "anylogic" tag, else you confuse other SOF users :)
